# Create Transparent CRichEditCtrl

Tags: mfc, transparency, transparent, cricheditctrl

I want to create Transparent CRichEditCtrl. Background will be CWnd.

**What I tried**

I tried by using WS_EX_TRANSPARENT. But in this case painting is not proper.
Other then that I tried OnCtlColor but it is not being called at all.
SetWindowRgn is not suitable for me.

Let me know if is there any way to make CRichEditCtrl transparent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render CRichEditCtrl on CDC with transparent backgorund ? (MFC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704074/how-to-render-cricheditctrl-on-cdc-with-transparent-backgorund-mfc)

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/richedit/article.php/c2407/Transparent-RichEditCtrl.htm